# React Native - How to re-render Navigator component on icon press

Tags: react-native

How would I re-render/ change the colour of a Navigator component icon when it is pressed. I have TouchableHighlight on it but I need the state to stay permanently. For example someone presses a 'favourite' heart icon, and it turns from grey to red. I've been trying to figure out a solution for some time now.

This is the section of my code where the change should happen. I need my if statement and Navigator icon to re-render based on the true/false value which changes when the TouchableHighlight onPress triggers.

```js
var NavigationBarRouteMapper = {

    RightButton: function(route, navigator, index, navState) {
        // * The button displayed in the top right of the navigator

        switch(route.id) {
            case('businessProfile'):
                if (route.isFavourited) {
                    return (
                        <View style={[ styles.multipleIcons ]}>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => {
                                    var favouriteBusiness = new FavouriteBusiness();
                                    favouriteBusiness.updateBusinessAsFavourite(route.business.id)
                                }}
                                style={[ styles.navBarButton, styles.iconRightPaddingLarge ]}
                                >
                                <IconFA
                                    name='heart'
                                    size={ 25 }
                                    color='#de6262'
                                    style={ styles.icon }
                                />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    );

                } else {

                    return (
                        <View style={[ styles.multipleIcons ]}>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => {
                                    var favouriteBusiness = new FavouriteBusiness();
                                    favouriteBusiness.updateBusinessAsFavourite(route.business.id)
                                }}
                                style={[ styles.navBarButton, styles.iconRightPaddingLarge ]}
                                >
                                <IconFA
                                    name='heart'
                                    size={ 25 }
                                    color='#ddd'
                                    style={ styles.icon }
                                />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    );

                }

            default:
                return null;
        }
    },
};

<Navigator
    ref='navigator'
    sceneStyle={ [styles.container, styles.inner] }
    initialRoute={{ 
        id: this.props.scene,
        title:this.props.title
    }}
    renderScene={ this.renderScene }
    configureScene={(route) => {
        if (route.sceneConfig) {
            return route.sceneConfig;
        }     
        return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
    }}
    navigationBar={
        <Navigator.NavigationBar
            routeMapper={ NavigationBarRouteMapper }
            style={ styles.navigationBar }
        />
    }
/>
```

Comment: Can you either show some of the code so far or maybe a screenshot of what you want accomplished? Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my question with the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

if you still did not get the solution perhaps these could help.
you can define some Properties in construktor:

```
  constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  color: 'lightgrey',
};
}
```

You can define the Icon in the RooteMapper of the Navigaton bar:

```
return (<Icon
                name="star"
                style={[styles.rightHadderButton, {color: this.state.color}]}
                onPress={RightNavigatorButton.favoriteStar.bind(this)}/>);
```

and then change the collor in the onpress defined Function:

```
 exports.favoriteStar = function(event) {
  if (this.state.color === 'lightgrey') {
    this.setState({ color: '#990000' });
    AlertIOS.alert( "favoriteStar","Favorite");
  } else {
    this.setState({ color: 'lightgrey' });
    AlertIOS.alert( "favoriteStar","notFavorite");
  }
}
```

Hope these works for you too and it helps you.